# I have an Issue Regarding jQuery and WordPress. Please Anyone explain this following code

Tags: jquery, wordpress, url, scroll, elementor

this code is for my problem . I want this to change url by sroling down but I want someone who can explain this to me.I have an Issue Regarding jQuery and WordPress. Please Anyone explain this following code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // Get the current section ID
  var sectionID = jQuery('section').filter(function() {
    return jQuery(this).offset().top <= jQuery(window).scrollTop() + 50;
  }).last().attr('id');

  // Update the URL
  history.pushState(sectionID, null, '#' + sectionID);

  // Listen for the user to scroll
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    // Get the current section ID
    var sectionID = jQuery('section').filter(function() {
      return jQuery(this).offset().top <= jQuery(window).scrollTop() + 50;
    }).last().attr('id');

    // Update the URL
    history.pushState(sectionID, null, '#' + sectionID);
  });

  // Listen for the user to click on the URL
  jQuery(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
    // Get the section ID from the URL
    var sectionID = event.state;

    // Scroll to the corresponding section
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: jQuery('#' + sectionID).offset().top
    }, 500);
  });
});


I want to use code for changing WordPress URL by scrolling down by sections`
```

Comment: The //Get the current section ID// finds the section that is in view when the page loads and adds it to the url using history.pushState(). Then the `jQuery(window).scroll(function() {` keeps firing as the user scrolls, and when a new section comes into view its id gets set in the url. The `jQuery(window).on('popstate'...` monitors when the url changes, and then scrolls to that section, including when the user clicks on an anchor link. Note that `jQuery('section')` is looking for `<section>..</section>`s, and they should have unique ids.

Comment: If you want to use divs, you should give them all a common class and still give them unique ids such as `<div class="scroll-section" id="section_1">...</div>`, and then replace the following selector across the code `jQuery('section')` with `jQuery('.scroll-section')`.